# sitefinity create a unscribers table in the database

Tags: sitefinity

Sitefinity by default create many necessary tables automatically for users , but it wont store the deleted subscriber information by creating a unsubscribes table. Are they any way to customize a new table in back end code to store deleted information?

Answer (score 0):

When a user unsubscribes from a newsletter, then the user is removed from the relevant Mailing List (**sf_notif_subscriptions** table, which is a linking table containing subscriber_id and mailing_list_id).

Then, a record is being added to the **sf_unsubscription_info** table.

Comment: To elaborate on my question ,  subscriber unsubscribes means the subscriber deletes his account in our system , I guess sitefinity don't have such  a table to store deleted subscriber information

Comment: how exactly a subscriber can delete their account?